# Why was my question about internal body nerve biology just killed? I explained "actual problem I face", with words others cited did too

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, specific-question

I have a question about my Biology Stack Exchange post: [Is the tube for anal and vaginal canal the same/equal sensitivity? I can feel a bowel's spatial dimensions; same ability to sense object internally?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/95156/is-the-tube-for-anal-and-vaginal-canal-the-same-equal-sensitivity-i-can-feel-a)

*I asked in chat at https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55208400#55208400 but the room does not seem active, so repeating here:*

- Can I ask if https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/95156 is locked for a reason (or should I wait for further
  comments/notifications)? 15:53
- I was reading [Silly question about two human mechanisms: induced "REM dreams" by masturbation?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/93632/silly-question-about-two-human-mechanisms-induced-rem-dreams-by-masturbation)
  and felt that my question was then on-topic.
- My question was just as deep as [Silly question about two human mechanisms: induced "REM dreams" by masturbation?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/93632/silly-question-about-two-human-mechanisms-induced-rem-dreams-by-masturbation),
  I used the same language.

https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask says "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems that you face.**" which I took to heart, I gave my "stack" as programmers say. **I was proud I stuck to (medical) words my doctor has used in the examination room** (and if I said "shit" my doctor said the word cordially back to me).

Before somebody guesses what I asked based on words I did not say, I did not say "does it feel XYZ?" I asked if you can identify the object inside, and to what degree (words I would have edited to add to my original question by now)?

I would challenge anybody to think (and explain) the wording I should have used to be mature? I thought literally decades about the question here so I think I know a few words about how others may think as well comparing and contrasting the ability to map/coordinates/blender.org/identify the object internally.

***I tried to be very sanitary with my language**. Which is why I understand but am surprised after using biology/medical terminology for most descriptors, and just the word "sh_t" for "doo doo" felt reasonable enough, and now I'm asking what is the actual language usage problem. I actually described some of my personal history ("my stack" as I wrote above) to try to balance and soften the blow of reading even if you are (ironically, hypersensitive like me) hypersensitive.*

*I was deliberately sanitary, dense, distant, and could have gone for the "Can you feel X/A/1 in your Y/B/2 like I feel in my Z/C/3?" directly but chose to use the indirect sounding medical terminology, which is legalese-like and wordy. I mean I tried to make the process sound technical, like I would in real life normally. I rarely (basically never) say the word "Sex" even, even never with friends either, my private searches being not known, and so the question in question is the 0.01% of my written public activity to make any mention of genital vocabulary. I made a sincere effort to use the dictionary/Wikipedia phrasing for body parts and did not make graphic language references besides that.*

*I made a puny "covering my ass" pun to be cordial with the subject matter I presented, given I am relating asking (to myself first, then here) as being a human individual being sensitive to **my own body alone; the only body being described is my own, and barely except generically**. I thought that might help calm some people down if the albeit appropriate words were still intense, I'd understand even vague mention can be triggering, but I've heard we all curse on the toilet (even in public bathrooms, vocal dignified cursing seems normal before/during plopping), I felt mature responders could thus manage to navigate.*

*I deliberately made an effort to require readers to read carefully and not just skim for trigger-words. **I figured if you could read how my voice would be as difficult for a doctor to parse, and how that doctor would realize I did not just want to talk about my ___hole directly (so I said "tube")**, the writing would be self-muted and self-censored enough.*

(So far I have the feeling the correct question wording would ultimately be the title of the peer-reviewed scientific literature *["Empirical Review of Conscious Biological Recognition of Inner Organ Sensitivity in the Human Body" I guess]*, the question in is going to be another question from the question going out, and I wanted to preserve that, to be mature, as well as the sciencey determination.

And am I being attacked for having a unique personal individual perspective and experience?)

In my original question I asked "Should I ask https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com or http://biology.stackexchange.com here?", was that an issue?

Is there a specific reason my question is being called into question, because I was not informed of any reason(?) so far.

Comment: I read Freud was wondering somewhat related to that in their writing, but he thought there were teeth, I think https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagina_dentata might help if we need to orcestrate the atmosphere, like normal on Stackexchange where Power Users ref a totally unrelated wiki as a discrete highly upvoted comment. That is, the teeth, apparently normal questions. Versus I mean where I come from... and that is a "Medical" issue I learned in grade school from a teacher, that is where I come from asking the question. I was proud I stuck to words my doctor has used in the examination room.

Comment: I just clicked on the link to your post. There I read " This post is hidden. It was flagged as spam or offensive content and deleted 15 hours ago by Community♦." So you *are* provided with a reason. If it wasn't spam, it was presumably regarded as offensive. I suspect that you will have to work out for yourself why.

Comment: @David Why is the other post (cited here) with the exact same vocabulary words not being treated the same? There should be a reason, and some ability to say what words were the problem exactly.

Comment: Don’t ask me. Perhaps it crept under the wire. This is a site administered by volunteer human beings who change from time to time. But you are using the worst possible argument, to which the easy answer would be “We missed that one. Thanks for drawing our attention to it. We’ll close it too.” There is a complaints procedure you can follow if you wish to use it, but I would suggest that the ”rights” we all have on this site are in proportion to the subscription we pay to use it.

Comment: @David I asked for an official reason and about what words were officially the issue, I did not complain, I asked a question.

Comment: I’ll leave you to wait for an answer then.

Comment: Sorry guys. This is hilarious. Also the amount of effort put into the defense here... What was the question? Are you asking whether orifices are able to sense stretching? They are all equipped with stretch receptors, just like the colon. And they are not identical in innervation and shape. Why would you suppose the vagina is *not* equipped with mechanoreceptors? Human mechanosensitivity has many uses... both biological and vulgar. Birthing children and intercourse, no less! If your question lacked common sense, without reason as to why this would not be the case... what are you protesting? :D

Comment: @SPr Thank you guy/gal. "Stetching" might have been the word I needed. Are you of enough Name and Reputation to answer my question during Lock Status? I would say you just gave the Answer to my Question, and I would have just Accepted Answer you for not being childish and being adult about what I asked. I think the missing words caused a lot of intimidating hilarity which is just as common for other stupid questions that have actual valid medical explanations. I did not (mean to or otherwise) ask/"protest" a + or - what receptors would be defineable, I just did not know their official naming.

Comment: I've rethought this a bit, and I think I read your original post as seeming a lot like a troll post, and it attracted flags from users who thought the same. Maybe you didn't mean it like that, though, and I didn't give you sufficient guidance to improve your question. The majority of your question focused on your own sexual experience rather than any biology of interest. If you can focus it to the biology itself and refrain from personal anecdote it might be a decent question. I'd suggest you focus on that question instead of worrying about specific words - @SPr's comment might help.

Comment: Also, if you're unsure how to word a question given this guidance, I'd be happy to open a private chat with you to help. Sex taboos can leak into and confuse biology, but I think it's quite possible to ask questions about physiology without invoking those taboos. I think discomfort with the subject might have led you to provide unnecessary information rather than focusing on the intended question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is nothing like the one you are comparing it to, and it only makes sense to make that comparison if you think the word "masturbation" is the reason your post was deleted; it is not.

Specific words were not the issue, their arrangement into sentences was.

As David quoted to you, your post "was flagged as spam or offensive content and deleted by Community♦".

I don't have any intent to continue this conversation.

Comment: Please distinguish between if my question was not flagged for "that" as you suggest specifically, then was I flagged as "offensive" or "spam" (how are those the same thing exactly?) specifically? Is there not a "Needs-Clarification" [clarification] tag versus instant-kill? I appreciate you using your real name, I am real name for me too. I am not questioning your intent, I am asking for a specific reason.